# Python subprocess stdin=subprocess.PIPE and unicode

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, subprocess

OK, a bit of back story.  I am writing a backup and recovery feature for my app.  I want to allow the encryption password for their backup file to allow any unicode character.  I am then constrained to using subprocess to actually run the backup command, which works fine using:

```
cmd = ['sudo', CMD_SCRIPT, 'python', script, 'backup', password, backup_to]    
subprocess.check_call(cmd)
```

I have been able to decrypt the file using the same unicode password and it seems to work just fine

My problem comes in the recovery phase; because the recovery process takes down my server that is being used to interface with the customer, I need this process to fire off in a separate deamon.  My code to accomplish this looks like:

```
cmd = ['python', script, 'restore', password, backup_file, 'user']
proc = subprocess.Popen(['at', 'now'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(' '.join(cmd))
```

When subprocess.PIPE attempts to write in this block of code (not mine, this is found in subprocess.communicate):

```
if self.stdin:
    if input:
        try:
            self.stdin.write(input)  # < HERE
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EPIPE and e.errno != errno.EINVAL:
                raise
    self.stdin.close()
```

it fails raising a UnicodeEncodeError:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xdc' in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have tried setting proc.stdin.encoding = 'utf-8' but it tells me that this attribute is read only, I have also tried setting env={'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf-8'} when I initialize my Popen instance.  Neither of these thing worked.

Is there another stdin object I can use that allows me to define encoding?  Please help.

Comment: use `nohup` instead to run something in the background without it being killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... I will halt the lynch mob on subprocess now.  This was completely my bad in being careless with mixing unicode and str types in python 2.

When passing a list to the check_call() command it appears as though there is some functionality to encode all unicode before making the command to the os.  when using communicate() it expects a single string, but passing a mix of unicode and str types in a list to the str type .join operation it was relying on pythons 'helpful' combining operations which default to encoding and decoding using 'ascii' as the codec.  **When I changed my code to ensure that everything was unicode in the list and then encoded it as I passed it to communicate things worked as expected.**  After ensuring my script, password and backup_file variables are of unicode type, my code now looks like:

```
cmd = [u'python', script, u'restore', password, backup_file, u'user']
proc = subprocess.Popen(['at', 'now'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(u' '.join(cmd).encode('utf-8'))
```

notice the 'u' prefix to my strings and that I then was able to define my own encodeing as utf-8 when I passed the string to communicate.